# Retrieve attributes from plain written text

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, tags, textarea

Lets say we have this text

> The 85 kilos guy rant 10 miles and then we can se he is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry and all of this in 2 hours

And we want to capture:

1. 85 kilos
2. 10 miles
3. 2 hours

I was trying think of a functions that could retrieve som atributes (atributes known already, of corse)

Lets say we want to detect:

Atribute: [amount] [mesure]

And our `mesures` are:

```
[miles, seconds, hours, minutes, times, kilos]
```

So i was thinking to explode the text in blankspaces, check if word in array (of mesures) and if previous word is a number, then i have an Atribute :D

(this is kind of pseudo/javascript code)

```
function get_mesure_attrs(txt){
     var text = txt.split(' ');
     for (i=1;i<=text.length;i++{    /*Note i begin with i=1 cause the first word would never be a mesure of a desired atribute */
         if(text[i] is in_array(mesures){
            if(is_number(text[i-1]){
                console.log('Atribute: '+text[i-1]+' '+text[i]);
            }
     }
}
```

I have no enough familarisation with related asociative arrays, so i was wondering if someone could give me a hint,

thanks a lot

Comment: Your approach is correct..so why not try it first? Not many people here on SO like answering questions with no attempted solution by the poster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str= "The 85 kilos guy rant 10 miles and then we can se he is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry and all of this in 2 hours 1 kilo",
measures = "mile|second|hour|minute|time|kilo";
function getMeasureAttrs(txt) {
  var re = RegExp( "\\b(\\d+)\\s(("+ measures +")s?)","g" );
  var attrs = [];
  txt.replace( re, function  ( $, $1, $2 ) {
    attrs.push ([ $1, $2 ] );
  })
  return attrs;
}
console.log(  getMeasureAttrs( str ) ); // [["85", "kilos"], ["10", "miles"], ["2", "hours"],["1","kilo"]]
```

for advance request

Comment: hey! this is looking great! how could we alter it to handle singular and plural? (one second, two seconds)

Comment: var re = RegExp( "\\b(\\d+)\\s("+ measures +")s?","g" );

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply! but are you sure?  I enter 1 kilo and it doesn't push it...

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using regular expressions:

```
function getMeasureAttrs(txt) {
  var re = /(\d+)\s+(miles|seconds|hours|minutes|times|kilos)/g;
  var match;
  while (match = re.exec(txt)) {
    console.log('Attribute: ' + match[1] + ' ' + match[2]);
  }
}
```

The two bracketed parts in the regular expression are what is matched. The first `(\d+)` means an integer number, and the second is the list of units you specified.